# Squashed navigation bar in iOS/Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

When trying to add a navigation bar to my simple iPhone app it just gets squashed together. The title is placed way too close to the menu bar (where the time etc is displayed). I placed the navigation bar so that the top of it aligns with the top of the view. The "height" property for it is greyed out and not possible to change.

http://gyazo.com/3b794aaf9b46117337210256324e8553

How do I get a normal-looking navigation bar?

Comment: Embed your UIViewController inside a UINavigationController instead?

Comment: Okay. Is there a way to copy paste UIView objects from one view to another in storyboard? @MikePollard